# How to force duplicate key insert mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I know this sounds crazy (And if I designed the database I would have done it differently) but I actually want to force a duplicate key on an insert. I'm working with a database that was designed to have columns as 'not null' pk's that have the same value in them for every row. The records keeping software I'm working with is somehow able to insert dups into these columns for every one of its records. I need to copy data from a column in another table into one column on this one. Normally I just would try to insert into that column only, but the pk's are set to 'not null' so I have to put something in them, and the way the table is set up that something has to be the same thing for every record. This should be impossible but the company that made the records keeping software made it work some how. I was wondering if anyone knows how this could be done?

P.S. I know this is normally not a good idea at all. So please just include suggestions for how this could be done regardless of how crazy it is. Thank you.

Comment: Remove the PK/Unique constraint.

Comment: Please post creation scripts for that table and a subset of supposedly duplicate data.

Comment: is it possible the primary key is actually the combination of this column and another column?

Answer (score 0):

A SQL Server primary key has to be ***unique*** and ***NOT NULL***. So, the column you're seeing duplicate data in cannot be the primary key on it's own. As urlreader suggests, it must be part of a composite primary key with one or more other columns.

How to tell what columns make up the primary key on a table: In Enterprise Manager, expand the table and then expand Columns. The primary key columns will have a "key" symbol next to them. You'll also see "PK" in the column description after, like this:

```
MyFirstIDColumn (PK, int, not null)
MySecondIDColumn (PK, int, not null)
```

Once you know which columns make up the primary key, simply ensure that you are inserting a combination of unique data into the columns. So, for my sample table above, that would be:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (MyFirstIDColumn, MySecondIDColumn) VALUES (1,1) --SUCCEED
INSERT INTO MyTable (MyFirstIDColumn, MySecondIDColumn) VALUES (1,2) --SUCCEED
INSERT INTO MyTable (MyFirstIDColumn, MySecondIDColumn) VALUES (1,1) --FAIL because of duplicate (1,1)
INSERT INTO MyTable (MyFirstIDColumn, MySecondIDColumn) VALUES (1,3) --SUCCEED
```

More on primary keys:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191236%28v=sql.105%29.aspx